# In Corda, how to start a flow from a service?

Tags: corda

I have created a `CordaService` running on my node. I want this service to start flows based on various conditions. However, the `ServiceHub` provided to the service does not provide the ability to start flows.

Is there any flow for a service to start a flow? How would I do thi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Simply pass your `CordaService` an `AppServiceHub` instead of a `ServiceHub` in its constructor.

The `AppServiceHub` interface extends the `ServiceHub` interface to give a node the ability to start flows:

```
interface AppServiceHub : ServiceHub {

    fun <T> startFlow(flow: FlowLogic<T>): FlowHandle<T>

    fun <T> startTrackedFlow(flow: FlowLogic<T>): FlowProgressHandle<T>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pass AppServiceHub to the constructor

In Kotlin:

```
class MyCordaService(private val serviceHub: AppServiceHub) : SingletonSerializeAsToken() {

    init {
        // code ran at service creation / node startup
    }

    // public api of service
}
```

or Java:

```java
public class MyCordaService extends SingletonSerializeAsToken {

    private AppServiceHub serviceHub;

    public MyCordaService(AppServiceHub serviceHub) {
        this.serviceHub = serviceHub;
        // code ran at service creation / node startup
    }

    // public api of service
}
```

**Important**: to avoid possible any potential deadlocks between running nodes, start inner flows from their own ***Thread***

For example:

```java
public class MyCordaService extends SingletonSerializeAsToken {

    private AppServiceHub serviceHub;

    public MyCordaService(AppServiceHub serviceHub) {
        this.serviceHub = serviceHub;
        // code ran at service creation / node startup
    }

    // public api of service
   public void doSomething(){   
    // do something and start a new flow
    Thread flowThread = new Thread(new StartFlow());
    flowThread.start();
   }

   private class StartFlow implements Runnable {
     @Override
        public void run() {
         // start new flow
         CordaFuture<SignedTransaction> cordaFuture=  appServiceHub.startFlow(new 
         Flow(params).getReturnValue();

         SignedTransaction signedTransaction = cordaFuture.get();
        }
   }
}
```